# Erro ao atualizar campos de valores com jquery;

Tags: jquery

Estou com problemas para atualizar o campo de valor líquido da minha página. Tenho os seguintes campos no meu HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="total" value="<?=$faturamento['valor_total'];?>" readonly name="valor" class="form-control">

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="frete" onchange="atualizaTotalLiquido()">

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="desconto" onchange="atualizaTotalLiquido()">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_liquido" value="<?=$faturamento['valor_total'];?>">
```

E esse é meu jquery;

```
function atualizaTotalLiquido(){
  var frete = $("#frete").val();
  var desconto = $("#desconto").val();
  var total = $("#total").val();
  var valor_liquido = $("#valor_liquido");
  var total_liquido = total+frete-desconto;
  valor_liquido.text(total_liquido);
}
```

Mas o campo de total liquido não muda.

---

Solução:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#frete').change(function(){
        atualizaTotalLiquido();
    });

    $('#desconto').change(function(){
        atualizaTotalLiquido();
    });

    function atualizaTotalLiquido(){

        var valor_liquido = 0;

        //var total_liquido = total+frete-desconto;

        valor_liquido = Number($("#total").val()) + Number($("#frete").val()) - Number($("#desconto").val());

        $('#valor_liquido').val(valor_liquido).toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Troque `.text` por `.val`.

Comment: Mesmo assim não dá certo. E eu tentei ainda fazer um log dos campos que busco e os valores vem, mas não dá certo.

Comment: Deu certo sim. Vou editar minha questão com a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bruno você está no caminho, porém há alguns trechos que não estão correto.

**Seu exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#frete').change(function(){
  atualizaTotalLiquido();
 });
 
 $('#desconto').change(function(){
  atualizaTotalLiquido();
 });

 function atualizaTotalLiquido(){
  
  var valor_liquido = 0;
      
  //var total_liquido = total+frete-desconto;
  
  valor_liquido = Number($("#total").val()) + Number($("#frete").val()) - Number($("#desconto").val());
   
  $('#valor_liquido').val(valor_liquido);
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <form class='form-control'>
   <!-- Valor de acordo com a variável que vem do banco ou de outro processo-->
   
   <label for="valor">Total</label> <br>
   <input type="number" id="total" readonly name="valor" class="form-control" value='5' > <br>

   <label for="frete">Frete</label> <br>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="frete"> <br>

   <label for="desconto">Desconto</label> <br>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="desconto"> <br>

   <label for="valor_liquido">Valor liquido</label> <br>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_liquido"> <br>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="master.js"></script>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Recomendo dar uma olhada no básico novamente.

[HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) -
[JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) -
[jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)