# Problema com calculo no valor total Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com problema pra recalcular o valor do campo OUTROS com o valor TOTAL. 
Preciso somar o valor colocado no campo outros na primeira vez, se eu mudar o valor preciso recalcular e somar a diferença: Por exemplo o valor total é 29,00 se eu colocar valor de outros 10,00 fica 39,00 mas se eu mudar pra 20,00 calcular a diferença e chegar no resultado 49,00. 
Atualmente meu problema é que está sempre incrementando quando altero o valor do campo outros e somando no total, se eu coloco 10,00 e altero o foco, calcula correto, mas se eu mudo pra 20,00 soma 10,00 + 20,00.

Segue imagem de ilustração e código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
let total  = 0;
$('#valout').on('change', function(){
    let valout = $(this).val();
    let subtot = replaceNumber($('#totalpedido').val());

    if(isNaN(valout)) valout = 0;
    if(isNaN(subtot)) subtot = 0;

    if(valout > 0) {
        $('#valout').data('val-default', valout);
        total   = subtot + valout;
    } else {
        let def = $('#valout').data('val-default');
        total   = subtot - def;
    }

    $('#totalpedido').val(replaceDecimal(total));
});
```

Comment: Na minha opinião você deveria executar o cálculo em uma função separada, isolar o comportamento de cálculo e após determinada ação você executar essa função, assim tanto na saída do focus quanto no change sempre teriam o mesmo comportamento de executar a mesma função, que sempre estaria fazendo o cálculo desde o início.

Comment: Tenta explicar melhor esse problema, divide ele em itens, fiquei bem confuso ao ler.

Comment: Verifique se essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357973/erro-ao-atualizar-campos-de-valores-com-jquery/357996#357996) lhe ajuda. Conforme o @FelippeTadeu comentou, seria melhor você separar a função do calculo e chamar conforme os eventos que necessita.

Comment: Editei aqui coloquei um gif, reparem no valor total

Comment: Mas seu gif está tão pequeno e desfocado que nem dá pra ver nada.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você declarou a variável `total` fora da função. Assim ela sempre irá somar com novos valores ao chamar o evento `change`. O correto é declarar ela dentro da função para sempre começar com o valor `0` para fazer novos cálculos:

```
$('#valout').on('change', function(){

    let total  = 0; // DECLARE AQUI

    let valout = $(this).val();
    let subtot = replaceNumber($('#totalpedido').val());

    if(isNaN(valout)) valout = 0;
    if(isNaN(subtot)) subtot = 0;

    if(valout > 0) {
        $('#valout').data('val-default', valout);
        total   = subtot + valout;
    } else {
        let def = $('#valout').data('val-default');
        total   = subtot - def;
    }

    $('#totalpedido').val(replaceDecimal(total));
});
```

Ou se você quer ela global, declare fora da função mas altere o valor para `0` dentro da função:

```
let total; // DECLARE AQUI
$('#valout').on('change', function(){

    total = 0; // Altera o valor

    let valout = $(this).val();
    let subtot = replaceNumber($('#totalpedido').val());

    if(isNaN(valout)) valout = 0;
    if(isNaN(subtot)) subtot = 0;

    if(valout > 0) {
        $('#valout').data('val-default', valout);
        total   = subtot + valout;
    } else {
        let def = $('#valout').data('val-default');
        total   = subtot - def;
    }

    $('#totalpedido').val(replaceDecimal(total));
});
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver isso, tentei fazer dessa forma mas nao obtive sucesso, neste [Link](https://media.giphy.com/media/1esqek5Knxu0vNuGjr/giphy.gif) mostra o problema melhor, sempre que eu colocar m valor no campo outros ele deve zerar e calcular novamente o valor atual ao invés de incrementar